# Words as Words—Dreyer’s English

Tags: punctuation

*Dreyer’s English*, by Benjamin Dreyer, is a new grammar and punctuation book I recently purchased.

To form plurals of words as words, he encloses the word in quotes and places the “s” outside the ending quote marks—a style I absolutely love and prefer.

Here’s an excerpt from his book:

*THERE’S A LOT OF DELETING IN COPYEDITING, not just of the **“very”s** and **“rather”s** and **“quite”s**  and excrescent **“that”s** with which we all encase our prose like so much Bubble Wrap and packing peanuts, but of restatements of information—“AS ESTAB’D,” one politely jots in the margin.*

My question to you (based on Dreyer’s approach) is, If a word already ends in an “s,” would you pluralize the word as word like this?

No suggested recast, please.

**Example 1**

There were one too many “as”s, “his”s, and “was”s in his first paragraph.

*or*

**Example 2**

There were one too many “as”es, “his”es, and “was”es in his first paragraph.

Would you personally go with example 1 or example 2 if you were following Dreyer’s approach for punctuating words as words based on how he does it (“very”s, “rather”s, “quite”s, etc.)?

Thank you.

Comment: Steven Poole (of the Guardian) is not quite as enamoured of Dreyer and has some balanced comments to make in his [review of Dreyer's English](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2019/may/30/dreyers-english-by-benjamin-dreyer-utterly-correct-guide-to-clarity-and-style).

Comment: I'd go with example 1. A dislocated es is unattractive.

Comment: What is placed in quotes is a entity on its own. In the given context, the (singular form of the) word when enclosed in quotes represents a "mention" as opposed to a "use" -- that way, an *-s* suffix is appropriate as it is independent of the contents within the quotes. Not just Dreyer or I but everyone does it as it is the most logical thing go do. HTH.

Comment: Thank you. Yes or no—could we apply the same principle to “which”s, “whereas”s, “yes”s and “no”s, “do”s and “don’t”s? These look good too, solely  following Dreyer’s examples?

Comment: If the only way of making an expression understandable is to rephrase it, you cannot reasonably say "no suggested recast" . If the only available choices without recasting are confusing, then the only reasonable way of communicating *is* to recast.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally go with #1 because of conciseness.  If you can save a word, syllable, letter or space without confusion, then do it.  #1 is shorter than but as clear as #2.